# Validate XML with xsd => no error when delete row in the xml file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xsd

I want to validate xml file with an xsd. It's already work when i put an incorect type but it's doesn't work when i delete row in my xml document. How do this?

```
<Test>
    <TestNode1>1</TestNode1>
    <TestNode2>true</TestNode2>
    <TestNode3>true</TestNode3>
    <TestNode4>true</TestNode4>
    <TestNode5>true</TestNode5>
</Test>

<xs:element name="Test">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="TestNode1" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="TestNode2" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="TestNode3" type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:element name="TestNode4" type="xs:boolean"/> 
      <xs:element name="TestNode5" type="xs:boolean"/>     
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When i remove the row who contains testnode4 for exemple... and when i use this =>

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
xmlSettings.Schemas = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();
xmlSettings.Schemas.Add(null, xsdUri);
xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
using (var xmlStream = File.OpenRead(xmlUri))
{
    var xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, xmlSettings);
    while (xmlFile.Read()) { }
}
```

It's work but i don't want this.I want to get error when row is missed.

Thanks.

Comment: The declaration looks consistent with what you say you want:  `Test` should be invalid if it has no `TestNode4` child.  The most obvious explanation for the absence of an error message would be that the validator is not actually running, or is not running with the schema document you want it to use.  Why do you believe your validation is working at all?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_sequence.asp.

> The sequence element specifies that the child elements must appear in
>   a sequence. Each child element can occur from 0 to any number of
>   times.

If you want your element to be present every time, you have to specify a minOccurs attribute.

Comment: Doesn't work, i add on one champ one occurs but i didn't get error when validate with my xsd

Comment: And default value is OneOccurs="1"

Comment: OneOccurs = "1" ? I think the correct way is minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"

Comment: If `minOccurs` is not specified, it defaults to 1.  So that's not the solution to the OP's problem.